# How to position grid items inside grid view with horizantal scroll

Tags: css

Here is jsfiddle example :

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/5210/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" class="grid-view">
     <div class="grid-item" ng-repeat="item in items">
         <p>
             {{item.name}}
         </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

what I am trying to do

1. when content overflow it should scroll horizantally but the scroll bar should be hidden.
2. inside each grid item content should be vertically align in middle.
3. if there is content overflow the arrow mark in left and right side come automatically to indicate there is more items.
4. grid items should be vertically align to middle of grid view

thanks in advance.